# Securing a site's data and combating spam and click bots

Tags: php, angularjs, security

I've recently began coding with AJAX and AngularJS and async GET and POST requests are really cool with PHP! I've come across a few issues that I'm not sure are of huge importance, but they do seem to be.

I have pretty much separate PHP files laying in a directory called postRequests. These files receive the post requests that are coded in my AJAX scripts. The only filtering I have is checking that so and so fields are numeric, so and so are strings, etc. and a quick "custom sanitation" function:

```
function sanitize($string) {
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($string));
}
```

Many of these AJAX calls are very simple such as a link that updates a user profile's criteria or a request that sends post comment data. However, these can easily be spammed by click bots and users can just type something and spam the comment button (although I do clear the textarea after each submission).

- Is this a worry, how can I combat a user from just submitting a "hiowheihewr" comment text after 5 seconds?
- Should I secure my user input data with something else?
- I have considered using an HTTP Authentication, but how would I store the password? In strings in my AngularJS script? Is this safe?

Furthermore, my MySQL database credentials are all stored in strings (not encrypted) in a file called constants.php that I reference whenever I make a database connection. Is this safe?

How should I be storing these sort of admin passwords and is this an issue I should even worry about (the click bots and the storing of passwords). How easy is it for someone to discover my PHP files that parse my POST requests, send a POST request to my php files, or discover my directory of files and read the php or JS scripts?

Comment: should a user be considered logged in to comment or make calls to these scripts? If so, upon login, set a `$_SESSION` that says they are logged in. In your PHP script, check the `$_SESSION` is set. If it is, allow the comment, if not, do nothing. I'm not entirely sure how you can stop a regular user from typing things like "hiowheihewr", but the session thing should stop some randoms from calling your script

Comment: Doesn't that mean a user can just register and then make those calls? And yes, they can only make those calls to the script if they are logged in, otherwise the script doesn't respond to any input. I'm just wondering how much of an issue is spam in general and how easy it is for someone to map up my directory, read my PHP files, and what data I should be securing and how

Comment: Stop using `mysql` extension now. Use `PDO` or `mysqli`

Comment: I don't see where I'm using mysql?

Comment: may bad, i only see `real_escape_string`. Take a look at `Prepared Statements`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Security**

The first magic word would be `Prepared Statements`. No need for `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

With prepared Statements, you define your input as input. No chance, that there would ever mysql injection happen then.

Also never trust a user's input. If you expecting a Phone Number, why should it have anything else then `0-9,-,/,`?

Sure you will need more santization, if we are talking about `shell_execute`, `eval` or something like that. Then it is very important to never trust the user input.

**Spam**

I always do it it via honey pot method. Make a link which is hidden via `CSS`. Something Like: `/submit-very-important-data.php`

If this page is called, you know it is called by a bot, and you can store this in a `SESSION`. If your site is not big enough, no one will care about a specific bot, just for your page.

Also only accept a Comment, if the user is more then 30 seconds (or something like that) on your page.

If this all does not work for you, you will need a captcha.

For all, `SESSION` will be your friend.

**Authentification**

Don't know `AngularJS`, but if the user is Authentificated, why not store in a `Session`?